# Conditionally returning a vector of some row values based on another column's row values

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

Here is a reproducible data set:

```
set.seed(55);
data <- rnorm(12);
dates <- as.POSIXct("2019-03-18 10:30:00", tz = "CET") + 0:(length(data)-1)*60;

R <- xts(x = data, order.by = dates) %>%
  sample(size = 10) %>%
  fortify.zoo()

colnames(R) <- c("Time", "Rf");
R$lab <- "A"
R$lab[c(5, length(R$lab))] <- "BB"
R$diff <- c(NA, diff(R$Rf))
```

Output looks like:

```
> R
                  Time           Rf lab       diff
1  2019-03-18 10:30:00  0.120139084   A         NA
2  2019-03-18 10:32:00  0.151582984   A  0.0314439
3  2019-03-18 10:33:00 -1.119221005   A -1.2708040
4  2019-03-18 10:34:00  0.001908206   A  1.1211292
5  2019-03-18 10:36:00 -0.505343855  BB -0.5072521
6  2019-03-18 10:37:00 -0.099234393   A  0.4061095
7  2019-03-18 10:38:00  0.305353199   A  0.4045876
8  2019-03-18 10:39:00  0.198409703   A -0.1069435
9  2019-03-18 10:40:00 -0.048910950   A -0.2473207
10 2019-03-18 10:41:00 -0.843233767  BB -0.7943228
```

I am trying to return the rows of column "diff" as a vector when the corresponding value of "lab" column is "A". But the condition is, for "BB" not only the corresponding diff value is dropped but also the two immediate values from upper and lower rows are also skipped.

Of the above example, following output is expected:

```
> res
[1]  0.0314439 -1.2708040  0.4045876 -0.1069435
```

Can you kindly help? Thanks

Comment: Don't end code lines with a semi-colon, R is not C. The semi-colon is the instruction separator so `instr1;` is **two** instructions: `instr1; NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
inds <- which(R$lab == "BB")
R$diff[-unique(c(inds - 1, inds, inds + 1))]
```

Or as @Rui Barradas mentioned

```
R$diff[-sapply(inds, `+`, -1:1)]
```

Comment: Upvote but simpler: `R$diff[-sapply(inds, `+`, -1:1)]`. (With backticks around the plus sign.)

Comment: @RonakShah,  I tried your code without using unique() which gives me the same result. Can you please explain why do we need to use unique() here?

Comment: Yes, it should work without `unique` as well. I used it here because for certain cases it is possible that some numbers overlap meaning two "BB" values are next to each other in such cases we get only unique index.